# Select distinct values of few columns and multiple values of few columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select distinct values of few columns along multiple values of few columns of same table. My table is like this

[image]

I want to select distinct values of first_name and last_name columns and all values of subject cloumn when displaying this table like this

[image]

Is it possible to display distinct values of first_name and last name?

```sql
Select DISTINCT `first_name` , `last_name` from table1
```

Comment: Consider handling data display related requirements in your Application code (eg: PHP). SQL is not suitable for the same

Comment: how select values of the subject as it is from the same table

Comment: Just run: `SELECT first_name, last_name, subject from table1` and then loop in your PHP code to club data as per your display needs

Comment: is there any way to do in sql coz i have add values of few cloumns

Comment: use `Group_Concat()` . Check this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: no it does not work it display values in a single row

Comment: `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table1 GROUP BY first_name, last_name;` check working example here -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=b3BtzRqmfq

Comment: thanks @AakashTushar but my display format includes subject cloumn also

Comment: How about `SELECT first_name, last_name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject) FROM table1 GROUP BY first_name, last_name;`? check here -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=b3BtzRqmfq

Comment: yes i am working like this hopefully it will serve the need thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with given scenario using partition by clause. Please check below sample code snippet. It works.

```
CREATE TABLE #Student                                                                  
(                                                                             
     first_name VARCHAR(100),                                                  
     last_name VARCHAR(100),                                                   
     [subject] VARCHAR(100)                                                            
)

INSERT INTO #Student (first_name, last_name, [subject]) VALUES ('a','b','maths')  
INSERT INTO #Student (first_name, last_name, [subject]) VALUES ('a','b','science')
INSERT INTO #Student (first_name, last_name, [subject]) VALUES ('e','f','bio')
INSERT INTO #Student (first_name, last_name, [subject]) VALUES ('e','f','eng')


SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN reportTbl.RowNo = 1 
            THEN first_name 
            ELSE '' 
    END as first_name,   
    CASE 
        WHEN reportTbl.RowNo = 1 
            THEN last_name 
            ELSE '' 
    END as last_name, 
    [Subject]  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         first_name, last_name, [Subject],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name  ORDER BY subject) RowNo 
     FROM 
         #Student) reportTbl
```

Actual table after added RowNo column with partition by clause:

[image]

This is the final output of the query:

[image]